# Spring Boot Maven project build error with STS

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I am getting the below error message while creating a new spring starter project in Spring STS

> project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test:security:1.3.8-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer 
>        org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.8.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was 
>        cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates 
>        are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.8.RELEASE 
>        from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>security</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>security</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath />
      <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>

   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

For every spring starter project I am getting the above error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should update your Spring boot parent dependency to to the latest realease 1.5.3:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Maven 2` or `Maven 3.x`?

According to the documentation, `Spring Boot` is compatible with Apache `Maven 3.2` or above (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-maven-installation)